# How to segue from one viewcontroller to another

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I have a problem about the segue

```
if signupError == nil {
    println("logged in")
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segue", sender:  nil)
} else {
    if let errorString = signupError!.userInfo?["error"] as? NSString {
        // Update - added as! String
        error = errorString as! String
    } else {
        error = "Please try again later."
    }

    self.displayAlert("Could Not Log In", error: error)
}
else {
    if let errorString = signupError!.userInfo?["error"] as? NSString {
        // Update - added as! String
        error = errorString as! String
    } else {
        error = "Please try again later."
    }
    self.displayAlert("Could Not Log In", error: error)
}
```

I'm quite sure for the first time it worked well, but when I sign out, it seems that the app remember some status, although I input the wrong password, and it shows alert and doesn't print logged in into the console, but it still segue

Comment: Do not change your post because your problem changed otherwise the answers below make no sense. If you solve the first problem mark the question as answered, press the up arrow to give the person that helped you a point and create a new question for you next problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Drag a segue from view controller1 to view controller2,not from any
   button
   [image]
2. Set a identifier of your segue

[image]

3. Use this function to fire a segue.

   `self.performSegueWithIdentifier("youridentifer", sender:nil);`

Comment: Hi, I met a new problem, when I log in by using the correct password and username, view controller will jump to second view controller which is correct. And I also add a button in the second view controller which is sign out. When I sign out, the app return to the first view controller and ask you to either log in or sign up, but no matter whether I input the correct password or not, when I click the log in, it just jump to the second view controller

Comment: That is the logic issue. You call `performSegueWithIdentifier ` only the login is success. I cant figure out what is the problem from the code you post.

Comment: I want to know is there a function that when I click the button, all things will reset

Comment: The code you post seems right. I think server request is the issue. Do you check  that when you log out and try to login again, you app does a server request again?Try to make a break point and log

Comment: while I think I just simply segue by using button, but I doesn't log out actuatlly, so how to deal with it

Comment: Just use new username and password to make a new server request. So,if new password is wrong, user can not login

Comment: I use a wrong username to log in, and I received an alert that the username is wrong, and it doesn't run  println("logged in"), but it run self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segue", sender:  nil) and segue